# Null check operator used on a null value - Riverpod Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, null, provider, riverpod

Okay I have a `FlutterFire` app and using `Riverpod` to manage the `state` of my app. I have a `Listenable Provider` named `userProvider` where I get the user data from `Cloud Fierestore`. Note that I have a `Stream Provider` which updates the `userProvider`. Here's what I mean:

```
Stream<UserModel> getUserData(String uuid) {
    return _users.doc(uuid).snapshots().map(
        (event) => UserModel.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
```

**That above is my Stream Provider and here's what I mean when saying it updates the state of my userProvider:**

```
 void getData(WidgetRef ref, User data) async {
    userModel = await ref
        .watch(authControllerProvider.notifier)
        .getUserData(data.uid)
        .first;
    ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => userModel);
  }
```

the above function is in my main.dart file.

**My userProvider is like this:**

```
 final userProvider = StateProvider<UserModel?>((ref) => null);
```

okay so I made it nullable because before sign in there'll be no user signed in meaning no data to hold.

When I try to use the userProvider I'm getting an error saying null check operator used on a null value but I use a null check operator because I'm certain the user is signed in now and there should be data store to that Provider.

> Plaese help me know what is wrong with my code.

**Thank you**

Comment: you can make static empty Usermodel to avoid nullable. learn the pattern from [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Kinda. I couldn't fix that problem but I used StateNotifierProvider and yeah everything worked as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first for `null` before accessing the data in the `Provider`.

to check `null` heres the code:

```
final user = userProvider.state;
if (user != null) {
  // use user
} else {
  // handle the case where user is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the provider state is reset, although I don't see you have an .autoDispose modifier. The use this way, you can track at what point in time the state of the provider turns into null:

```dart
final userProvider = StateProvider<UserModel?>((ref) {
  ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
    print('$next => $previous');
  });

  ref.onDispose(() {
    print('userProvider has been disposed');
  });
});
```

I think it's a great way to stop provider nulling :) Debugging is everything.

Comment: Fam I did as you suggested and this was printed on my log: `null => null`. It is as if no data was stored in that provider. Another thing printed was my `userModel` with each field having it's relevant data that was passed in when signing in but then it says it is all null. Too bad can't print it here due to it having many characters. It shows `userModel` like this: `userModel{all the relavant data} ==> null`. Any further suggestions??

Comment: does the `onDispose` method print anything?

Comment: No it doesn't print anything. I don't understand now

Comment: Maybe you update the states of different providers `userProvider`?The way I see it (pseudocode): if the user is authenticated => `userProvider.state = userModel(data)` => and after that you do not change the state of `userProvider` anywhere else, but only read. The provider state should then not be null. As soon as you change it again, one `userModel` is replaced by another

Comment: I only update the state of `userProvider` afetr sign-up and that code in my `main.dart` - the `getData` function. That could be the reason

Comment: Okay I tried again and this time it printed `userModel` on my log but when I use the provider I get the null check error. Perhaps the problem is how I call the `provider`. Here's how I do it: `late UserModel userModel;

  void getUserProvider() {
    userModel = ref.read(userProvider.notifier).state!;
  } `      then I do `userModel.username` to get the username

Comment: maybe try use `UserModel? userModel`?

Comment: Nothing is working but thanks for your effort